# systemd & logrotate: missing error messages in systemd journal

Tags: linux, systemd, logrotate, timer

I have just discovered a problem that I don't understand (SLES15 SP2):

I had mis-configured one `logrotate` service (in `/etc/logrotate.d`).
In SLES 15 `logrotate.service` is triggered by `logrotate.timer` daily.

However my mis-configured service seems to log an error message only once (which was the main reason I did not discover the problem for a long time).

Can anybody explain what is going on?
Other logrotate services seem to be executed (I'm not sure).

### Some Details

The error from logrotate was caused by a failed `postrotate` action,
specifically the failure to send `SIGHUP` to the running process.

### Syslog messages:

```text
Dec 18 00:00:20 h16 systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Dec 18 00:00:20 h16 logrotate[41799]: Failed to kill unit \x7b__SERVICE__\x7d.service: Unit \x7b__SERVICE__\x7d.service is not loaded.
Dec 18 00:00:20 h16 logrotate[41799]: error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/iotwatch/MD10/*.log '
Dec 18 00:00:20 h16 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 18 00:00:20 h16 systemd[1]: Failed to start Rotate log files.
Dec 18 00:00:20 h16 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 18 00:00:20 h16 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was confused about the absence of further error messages, assuming that would be caused by `logrotate` no longer executing.

However when the `postrotate` action failed, it meant that the old logfile was renamed, but (due to the failure in `postrotate`) the daemon continued to write into the renamed file (instead of being triggered by `postrotate` to create a new one to write to).

In turn that meant that `logrotate` would not find a logfile to rotate, which consequently also meant that no `postrotate` action was to be executed.
So finally when no `postrotate` is executed, it cannot trigger an error, so no messages in syslog.